# Two consequence bars in a chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, charts, bar

I have bar chart that consists of 4 bars. I want to add extra four bars so that I can compare the result of each algorithm before and after a certain modification. the bar I have is the following:

[image]

and I want something like this (Except that each 2 bars has the same color so each algorithm before and after has the same color):

[image]

The code of my first image is:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}


%-------------------------------------------------------
%Pseudo Code
\floatname{algorithm}{Pseudo Code}

%-------------------------------------------------------
%Bar chart
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}%رمادي
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}%
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{252,252,252}%
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}%كحلي غامق
\definecolor{RYB5}{RGB}{85, 114, 155}%
\definecolor{RYB6}{RGB}{67, 94, 132}%



%------------------------------------------------------
%Tiks figure
\usetikzlibrary{fit, backgrounds, matrix, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{ 
    startstop/.style={ 
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1.8cm, 
        minimum height=1.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB2 
    }, 
    process/.style={ 
        rectangle, minimum width=3.95cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=RYB1
    }, 
    arrow/.style={ 
        black,-{Stealth[length=6pt]} 
    },     
    arrowlabel/.style={
        midway, above, inner ysep=2pt 
    }, 
    dasharrow/.style={ 
        black, dashed,-{Stealth[length=6pt]} 
    } 
}



\newcommand\stupidfbox[1]
  {%
    \fbox{\scantokens{#1\ignorespaces}}%
  }



\begin{document}



 \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering    
                    
                    
                                        \begin{tikzpicture}
                                    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
                                    xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
                                    xtick={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
                                    ylabel=Measure(\%),
                                    ymajorgrids,
                                    bar width=17pt,
                                    ]
                                    \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB2] coordinates {(alg1,44.71)};
                                    \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB1] coordinates {(alg2,26.57)};
                                    \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB4] coordinates {(alg3,37.57)};
                                    \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB5] coordinates {(alg4,39.57)};
                                    
                                    \end{axis}
                                \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Figure name}
            \label{fig:results_1}
        \end{figure} 
        
        


\end{document}
```

Does anyone knows how can I achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Most of the efforts in writing this went into removing things that were not needed. And to get the result, I moved `ybar` to the axis options and then added the plots without it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}%AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}%
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{252,252,252}%
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}%AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB5}{RGB}{85, 114, 155}%
\definecolor{RYB6}{RGB}{67, 94, 132}%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering    
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
     xtick={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     ylabel=Measure(\%),
     ymajorgrids,
     bar width=17pt,ybar,enlargelimits=0.1
     ]
     \addplot[fill=RYB1] coordinates {(alg1,44.71) 
     (alg2,26.57) (alg3,37.57) (alg4,39.57)};
     \addplot[fill=RYB4] coordinates {(alg1,24.71) 
     (alg2,16.57) (alg3,27.57) (alg4,59.57)};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Figure name}
 \label{fig:results_1}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, a small modification is it possible to make each two bar with the same color (each algorithm has its own color)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My apology definitely I will mention your answer in that question! I didn't meant to make it as my effort. Please check the date of my edit to make sure if my edit before or after your answer. Thank you once again.