# Change the color of two consequence bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, charts, bar

I  have a bar chart where the first bar of each of two bars have the same color and the same for the second bar. The bar chart I have is the following:

[image]

The code to produce it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}%AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}%
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{252,252,252}%
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}%AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB5}{RGB}{85, 114, 155}%
\definecolor{RYB6}{RGB}{67, 94, 132}%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
 \centering    
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
     xtick={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     ylabel=Measure(\%),
     ymajorgrids,
     bar width=17pt,ybar,enlargelimits=0.1
     ]
     \addplot[fill=RYB1] coordinates {(alg1,44.71) 
     (alg2,26.57) (alg3,37.57) (alg4,39.57)};
     \addplot[fill=RYB4] coordinates {(alg1,24.71) 
     (alg2,16.57) (alg3,27.57) (alg4,59.57)};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Figure name}
 \label{fig:results_1}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to make each two bar charts have the same color?

The original code I have post is taken from @marmot 's answer in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475096/two-consequence-bars-in-a-chart). Special thanks for his/her effort it is really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question well. If you want two bars to have the same color, just use the same color option in `\addplot`. Here I use `RYB4`

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}%AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}%
\definecolor{RYB3}{RGB}{252,252,252}%
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}%AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA
\definecolor{RYB5}{RGB}{85, 114, 155}%
\definecolor{RYB6}{RGB}{67, 94, 132}%

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
     xtick={alg1,, alg2,,alg3,, alg4},
     ylabel=Measure(\%),
     ymajorgrids,
     bar width=17pt,ybar,enlargelimits=0.1
     ]
     \addplot[fill=RYB4] coordinates {(alg1,44.71) 
     (alg2,26.57) (alg3,37.57) (alg4,39.57)};
     \addplot[fill=RYB4] coordinates {(alg1,24.71) 
     (alg2,16.57) (alg3,27.57) (alg4,59.57)};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

In case you want each `alg` has the same color, this is a non-`pgfplots` solution

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Axis
\draw (0,1.3) rectangle (5.5,6.5);
\foreach \i in {2,...,6} {
    \draw[thin,gray!50] (0,\i)--(5.5,\i);
    \draw (0,\i) node[left] {\i0} -- (.1,\i);
}
\foreach \i [count=\ct] in {0.5,2,3.5,5} {
    \draw (\i,1.3)--(\i,1.2) node[below] {alg\ct};
    \draw (\i,6.5)--(\i,6.6);
}
\node[rotate=90,above=4ex] at (0,3.9) {Measure (\%)};
% Bars
\path[fill=red,draw=black,very thin] (0,1.3) rectangle (0.475,4.471) (0.525,1.3) rectangle (1,2.471);
\path[fill=yellow,draw=black,very thin] (1.5,1.3) rectangle (1.975,2.657) (2.025,1.3) rectangle (2.5,1.657);
\path[fill=green,draw=black,very thin] (3,1.3) rectangle (3.475,3.757) (3.525,1.3) rectangle (4,2.757);
\path[fill=blue,draw=black,very thin] (4.5,1.3) rectangle (4.975,3.957) (5.025,1.3) rectangle (5.5,5.957);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, he wants each new pair to be the same color. But not all of the same color.

Comment: @AndréC Yes, thank you for clarifying my question, and thanks to JouleV for his effort.

Comment: @CSStudent You're welcome.